# Using an xml file in my view child class

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity class that creates a view child object

```
public class DaDActivity extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(new DragSurface(this));
   }
}
```

Here is my DragSurface.java

```
public class DragSurface extends View{

   public DragSurface(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);

   }
}
```

And also I have dragsurface.xml file but I dont know how to use this xml file in my DragSurface.java.I mean I want DragSurface.java works with background,buttons or something like that in dragsurface.xml but I could not link .java to .xml

Thanks for help..

Comment: can you explain your requirement clearly

Comment: Activity will create DragSurface object which extends View and DragSurface will be displayed with using dragsurface.xml.But I can not connect DragSurface.java to dragsurface.xml yet.How I can do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout,null);
```

try the above line to inflate your xml file.
try the below code:::

```
public class DaDActivity extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(new DragSurface(this).createView());
   }
}
```

Here is my DragSurface.java

```
public class DragSurface extends View{

   public DragSurface(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
   }
   public View createView(){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout,null);
        return view; 
     }
}
```

Comment: I tried in the constructor but doesnt work

View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout,null);

I guess I do something with the 'view' right ??